# Best method for initializling the Okuma API if I want a program that works for both lathe and mills?

Tags: api, okuma

I am writing a program that will run on both lathe and machining centers.  How best can I initialize the API without doing during loading.  Should I call a class for each machine type or can I call each (and close them) within the same class?

Added example of current method for just Lathe...

```
 using Okuma.CLDATAPI.DataAPI;
 using Okuma.CLDATAPI.Enumerations;
 using Okuma.CLDATAPI.Structures;
 using Okuma.CLDATAPI.DataAPI.MacMan;

 public class LatheDutyOnline
 {
 private CMachine Objl;
 private CVariables Objlv;
 private CIO IO;
 private CATC ObjAtc;
 private CAxis objaxis;
 private CBallScrew objBS;
 private CProgram objProgram;
 private CSpec objSpec;
 private CSpindle objSpindle;

 private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Objl = new CMachine();
        Objl.Init();
        Objlv = new CVariables();
        IO = new CIO();
        ObjAtc = new CATC();
        objaxis = new CAxis();
        objBS = new CBallScrew();
        objProgram = new CProgram();
        objSpec = new CSpec();
        objSpindle = new CSpindle();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have enough to go on in this question to offer any suggestions. Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: I added the code I would use currently.  I want also have the program work for a machining center.  This would require some of the same objects.

Comment: What's going on with these Okuma questions?  Is the manufacturer sending its customers here?  That isn't going to work if nobody uses a proper tag.

Comment: None of us have enough points to make a tag yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a routine to check the current machine type. Something like this:

```vb
Private Sub CheckMachineType()  
    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\OSP-P\SHAREDDLL\LDATAPI.DLL") And   System.IO.File.Exists("C:\OSP-P\VOLANTE\CRAD\LCMDAPI.EXE") Then  
        MachineType = Lathe  
    ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists("C:\OSP-P\SHAREDDLL\MDATAPI.DLL") And System.IO.File.Exists("C:\OSP-P\VOLANTE\CRAD\MCMDAPI.EXE") Then    
        MachineType = MachiningCenter  
    Else  
        MachineType = NonOSP  
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can initialize the correct API type based on the value of MachineType.

---

## UPDATE

We now have a standard machine agnostic library that is perfect for this.
Please have a look at the sample program for SCOUT.

- https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK/tree/master/Scout

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [c# intro to Interfaces](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjboaM6-PQs) and this video [using .Net interfaces for machine neutral applications](http://thincster.com/2012/02/16/using-net-interfaces-for-machine-neutral-thinc-applications/). Using interfaces allows you to program against the interface instead of directly against the API.